# How to redirect from subdomain to old blogger address

Tags: blogger

My blog was on the subdomain blog.madamastrology.com on blogger platform, but now I want to back on madamastrology.blogspot.com. How to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Go into `Settings` > `Basic` > `Publishing` then in "Blog address" click the X in the top right hand corner of the box.

This will remove your custom domain from your Blogger blog and reset it to the default something.blogspot.com URL.

If you still want your subdomain to redirect, you'll have to change where that CNAME points to (put your default blogspot URL).

Note: Posts linked to on the subdomain won't redirect to the default domain! This only works for the root.